# How to scale (outer) element the same as (inner) img element using html and css?

Tags: html, css

My goal is to align `<h1>` on top of and alongside the bottom part of an `<img>` using css and html. When you scale the window, the size of the image will increase (both vertically and horizontally), and I want the text to be aligned on top of the image, following the bottom line. Currently I am using some percentage of the width and height to align the text, but you never know if the text will actually be aligned at the bottom.

I have also included an example with a desired result. The red box with the blue text aligned to the bottom is what I want to accomplish, and I have used an element with variable height and width.

I therefore thought if it was possible to scale the container of the `<img>` proportional to the image itself, I could achieve the same result.

## Some extra information

- I do *not* want to use css grid
- I do *not* know the ratio of the images in my application.

### I have the following css and html

```css
container{
  position:relative;
  height:100%;
}
img{
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  z-index:1;
}
h1{
  position:absolute;
  top:30vw;
  left:50vw;
  color:red;
  z-index:10;
}

.variable-container{
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
  height:70vw;
  width:50vw;
  background-color:#de2d3d;
}
h2{
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:10px;
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <h1>Title</h1>
   <img src="https://placebear.com/g/200/100.jpg">
</div>


<!-- This is what I am trying to accomplish -->
<div class="variable-container">
  <h2> 
  Aligned bottom of box
  </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you expecting something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ddrx4ppp/ (first example demonstrates some issues with image aspect ratios, so there is also a `background-image` alternative to refer to). *Note:* You can manually resize the containing element (bottom-right corner) for the sake of demonstration.

Comment: Your problem description ins’t really clear to me, can you show a picture of the desired result? Why is the image itself absolutely positioned, that is probably about the worst approach possible considering that you more or less _want_ the image size to influence how other elements behave ...

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Yes, that is exactly what I want. If you post your answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for your comment. You are right, and that was part of the problem with my solution. The image should *NOT* be positioned absolute. Also If you run the snippet there is an example of what I want to achieve. There is some blue text aligned at the bottom of a red container. UncaughtTypeError gave me an example on how to solve my issue.

Comment: Glad I could help, @John - you'll notice I've added the answer officially with a breakdown of the changes applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the primary issue here is that the nested `img` element has been positioned `absolute`, *taking it out the normal document flow*. Because of this, the outer element (containing parent element) is unable to scale according to inner element (nested element) as it is no longer relative to the document flow.

#### Summary of changes:

**Positioning of nested `img` element:**

- The nested `img` element `position` property changed from `absolute`
  to `relative`, this property could probably be removed altogether (as
  it doesn't seem necessary in this scope)

**Positioning of nested `h1` element:**

- The positioning of the nested `h1` element has also been reworked, to
  horizontally center an *absolutely positioned* element you could
  always simply declare `left` and `right` properties with the unit
  value of `0`, and since `h1` is a *block* element, simply declare
  `text-align: center` to center the text.
- For consistent positioning relative to the containing element, use
  the `bottom` property instead of the `top` property; since the
  requirement is to have this element remain positioned relative to the
  bottom of the containing element. If the requirement where the
  antithesis (positioned relative to the top of the containing
  element), then using the `top` property would be applicable.

**Image aspect ratio issues:**

- The first example demonstrates some issues with image aspect ratios,
  so there is also a `background-image` alternative to refer to as
  well.

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

*Note: You can manually resize the containing element (bottom-right corner) for the sake of demonstration.*

```css
.container{
  position:relative;
  height:100%;
}
img{
  position: relative; /* to scale outer el same as inner el, inner el can't be out of normal document flow */
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  z-index:1;
}
h1{
  position:absolute;
  /* rather use `bottom` property if text needs to stay at bottom, and use an absolute unit value like `px` for most consistent positioning */
  bottom:30px; 
  /* simply center an absolutely positionied element with properties `left` & `right` with values of `0` */
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center; /* then center text of block element */
  color:red;
  z-index:10;
  margin: auto; /* unset vendor margin property */
}

.bg-img {
    background-image: url(https://placebear.com/g/200/100.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
}

/* For the sake of demonstration */
.resize-demonstration {
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 2px dashed #ccc;
}
```

```html
<h2>Embedded Image</h2>
<div class="resize-demonstration">
  <div class="container">
     <h1>Title</h1>
     <img src="https://placebear.com/g/200/100.jpg">
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Background Image</h2>
<div class="resize-demonstration">
  <div class="container bg-img" style="height: 300px">
     <h1>Title</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle Demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/ddrx4ppp/)